# Problema con bucle for Javascript

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

Tengo una variable

```
afks afks[0] = {name: "pepe", id:1}
```

Cuando pongo en la función `console.log(afks)` sale bien, pero en el for me tira `undefined`:

```
function afksComando(player) {
  afks.push({ name: "pepe" }, { name: "pepe2" }, { name: "pepe3" });
  if (afks.length > 0) {
    let nombres = [];

    for (let i = 0;i < afks.length; i++) {
      nombres.push(afks[i].name);
    }

    let list = nombres.join(",");

    room.sendAnnouncement("[" + emojis.info + "]" + " Jugadores Afk: " + list, player.id);
  } else {
    room.sendAnnouncement("[" + emojis.info + "]" + " Jugadores Afk: -", player.id);
  }

  return false;
}
```

No se si estoy haciendo algo mal.
Gracias por leer

EDITADO

Comment: Creo que debes complementar tu pregunta... hablas de que pones un console.log y que sale bien... pero ese console.log no se ve en el código.. y la primera linea donde defines la variable está muy rara (a menos que sea un error de cuando escribiste la pregunta)
Donde estás poniendo el console.log que si funciona?

Comment: te falta el i < antes de el afks.length en el bucle for

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Hernan. Que error mas tonto se me paso

Comment: Y a vos pipe gracias. Soy nuevo aca y no soy bueno explicando. Gracias

Comment: favor [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/449927/edit) tu pregunta y agrega el código que no habías agregado en tu ciclo for. preguntas que han sido un error de escritura terminan siendo cerradas.